# Tornado motor and tornado.concurrency

Tags: python, mongodb, twisted, tornado

First of all, how can I simplify syntaxes when I need to query from three different collections:

```
@gen.coroutine
def _prepare_comment_extra(self, extra):
    (material, _), _ = yield gen.Task(self.db["material"].find_one,
        {"_id": extra["material_id"]})
    (course, _), _ = yield gen.Task(self.db["course"].find_one,
        {"_id": extra["course_id"]})
    (theme, _), _ = yield gen.Task(self.db["theme"].find_one,
        {"_id": extra["theme_id"]})
    raise gen.Return({
        "material": material,
        "course": course,
        "theme": theme})
```

For me it looks very daunting. Is there any way to write it more clearly ?!

The second question is about using motor with tornado.concurrent. I found that it is impossible to use motor operations in ThreadExecutor. It raises exception "Cannot switch to next thread". I know, that ThreadExecutor is assigned for executing blocking task in asynchronous manner. But then, could we execute motor in synchronous mode with the same connection ?

Final question:
What happens if we will use add_callback in run_on_executor function ?! Will we exit from ThreadExecutor, won't we ?

```
class SomeClass(...):
    @tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
    def test_fun(self, *a, **kw):
         ....
         ....
         self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : partial(fn, *args, **kwargs)
         ...
         ...
```